# Url redirects to xampp page instead of main site | Laravel

Tags: laravel, xampp

I an trying to setup a site locally but for some reason, everytime I try to browse the main url I redirects me to localhost.

I cloned the repository, ran composer update, created a new .env and ran php artisan key:generate

Afterwards I ran php artisan serve command and it gave me the url:

```
<http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

When I type that url in the browser, the page redirects me to the following url:

```
http://localhost/dashboard/
```

The following is the full path to the website:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\lrvl-absa-onboarding-v1
```

Anything I am doing wrong with the setup ?

Comment: Have you setup any `Virtual Hosts` ? If yes remove that and try then.

Comment: @Iftikhar uddin I just did it and yet I am experiencing the same result

Answer (score 0):

Just use the php artisan command and then go to 127.0.0.1:8000 on your browser. Make sure youre using the 8000 port

Comment: it's exactly what I am doing and it redirects me to xampp/dashboard

Comment: Just to mention that if I run a fresh installation everything works just fine